# Save the column header that is clicked on

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I'm really new to reactJS. I have a table with two columns. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination'

const Table = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);
    const [valueHeader, setValueHeader] = useState({title: "",body: ""}); //Value header state
    const [sortedUsers, setSortedUsers] = useState([]);

    const pageItemCount = 15
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0)
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getUsers(search);
            setUsers(response.data.users);
            setPageCount(Math.ceil(response.data.users.length / pageItemCount))
            setCurrentUsers(response.data.users.slice(0, pageItemCount))
        } catch (error) { }
    }, [search]);

    const sortFn = (userA, userB) => {
        // sort logic here, it can be whatever is needed
        // sorting alphabetically by `first_name` in this case
        return userA[valueHeader.body].localeCompare(userB[valueHeader.body]) //<== Use value of column header
      }
      
      useEffect(() => {
          if (isSorted) {
            setSortedUsers(currentUsers.slice().sort(sortFn))
          } else {
            setSortedUsers(currentUsers)
          }
        }, [isSorted, currentUsers, valueHeader]) //<== add valueHeader to dependency
      
      const toggleSort = ({target}) => {
        
        setIsSorted(!isSorted)
        setValueHeader({
          title: target.value,
          body: target.value === "name" ? "first_name" : "mobile"
        }) //<=== set state of value header
      }

    const changePage = (i) => {
        setCurrentPage(i)
        const startItem = ((i - 1) * pageItemCount) + 1
        setCurrentUsers(users.slice(startItem - 1, (pageItemCount * i)))
    }

    const handleChange = (event, value) => {
        changePage(value);
    }
        
            return (
                <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
                   
                    <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                                <th className='p-2' onClick={(e) => toggleSort()}>name</th>
                                <th className='p-2' onClick={(e) => toggleSort()}>mobile</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {sortedUsers.map((item, index) =>
                                <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                                    <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.first_name}</td>
                                    <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.mobile_number}</td> 
                                </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <Pagination className="mt-2 pb-20" dir='ltr' page={currentPage} count={pageCount} onChange={handleChange} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
                </div>
            )
        }
        
        export default Table
```

I want to make a decision based on the clicked column header. For example, if `name` column header is clicked, I want to use the value of `first_name` in `useFunc` and if `mobile` column header is clicked, I want to use `mobile_number` value in `useFunc`.

So how can I save which column header is selected and use it in other parts of my code, for example in `useFunc`?

Comment: You want to save entire column DOM or just value of which you selected?

Comment: I have a column header `name`, the rows of this column consists of `item.first_name`, similarly I have a column header `mobile`, its rows consists of `item.mobile_number`. I want to save which column header(`name` or `mobile`) is clicked on, then if, for example, `name` is selected, I want to use the value of `item.first_name` in other parts of my code (For example, if you look at my code, I have used `first_name` value in `sortFn` function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More easy and secure is to pass the value direcly to the function, if you want only the value

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'
    
    const Table = () => {
    
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
        const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
        const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);
        const [sortedUsers, setSortedUsers] = useState([]);
    
    
        useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getUsers(search);
            setUsers(response.data.users);
        } catch (error) { }
    }, [search]);
    
    const sortFn = (userA, userB) => {
      // sort logic here, it can be whatever is needed
      // sorting alphabetically by `first_name` in this case
      return userA.first_name.localeCompare(userB.first_name)
    }
    
useEffect(() => {
        if (isSorted) {
          setSortedUsers(currentUsers.slice().sort(sortFn))
        } else {
          setSortedUsers(currentUsers)
        }
      }, [isSorted, currentUsers])

    const toggleSort = () => {
      setIsSorted(!isSorted)
    }

    const useFunc = () => {
      //I want to decide based on the selected column header
    }
    
        return (
            <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
               
                <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                            <th className='p-2' onClick={(e) => toggleSort("name")}>name</th>
                            <th className='p-2' onClick={(e) => toggleSort("mobile")}>mobile</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {sortedUsers.map((item, index) =>
                            <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                                <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.first_name}</td>
                                <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.mobile_number}</td> 
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Table
```

Answer (score 0):

**Soluton**

Pass `value` of column header to a `state`, then use it for apart of your code and add `valueHeader` to `useEffect dependency` where you setSortedUsers like below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../../services/userService'

const Table = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState(false);
    const [valueHeader, setValueHeader] = useState({title: "",body: ""}); //Value header state
    const [sortedUsers, setSortedUsers] = useState([]);


    useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getUsers(search);
        setUsers(response.data.users);
    } catch (error) { }
}, [search]);

const sortFn = (userA, userB) => {
  // sort logic here, it can be whatever is needed
  // sorting alphabetically by `first_name` in this case
  return userA[valueHeader.body].localeCompare(userB[valueHeader.body]) //<== Use value of column header
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (isSorted) {
      setSortedUsers(currentUsers.slice().sort(sortFn(userA, userB)))
    } else {
      setSortedUsers(currentUsers)
    }
  }, [isSorted, currentUsers, valueHeader, sortFn(userA, userB)]) //<== add valueHeader add sortFn(userA, userB) to dependency

const toggleSort = ({target}) => {
  setIsSorted(!isSorted)
  if(target.value){
    setValueHeader({
    title: target.value,
    body: target.value == "name" ? "first_name" : "mobile_number"
  }) //<=== set state of value header
 }
}

const useFunc = () => {
  //I want to decide based on the selected column header
}

    return (
        <div dir='rtl' className='bg-background mt-10 px-5 rd1200:px-30 overflow-auto'>
           
            <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={toggleSort}>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2' onClick={toggleSort}>mobile</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {sortedUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.first_name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.mobile_number}</td> 
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table
```

Comment: when I click on a header, the page becomes blank

Comment: what is error in console log of browser

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks. In case we have more than 2 columns, how we should change `body: target.value == "name" ? "first_name" : "mobile_number"`?

Comment: I figured a problem. Regardless of which column header I click on, body takes `mobile_number` value.

Comment: @free if you have more than 2 columns, just create a function, in this function have switch case to return the value you want

Comment: OK, I will handle it, but in the existing code, even when I click on the `name` column header, the table is sorted based on the `mobile_number`. It seems that the `target.value` value is `undefined` and this is why sorting is done based on the `mobile_number`

Comment: @free where `sortedUsers` you get from?

Comment: I added the related state and where its value is set.

Comment: @free add `valueHeader` to dependence of useEffect where you `setSortedUsers`, i had updated my code

Comment: I added `valueHeader`, but the problem is not solved and the `target.value` value is `undefined`. by the way, I have this warning `Line 42:12:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'sortFn'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Comment: @free i have updated my code, i am have a question why you not pass argument to `sortFn` when you call it? i have added to my post answer.

Comment: but I get errors this way! Here is the error: `'userA' is not defined` & `'userB' is not defined`

Comment: @free Yeah, because you not yet define it, i don't know the value of userA and userB you get from.

Comment: Well, I tried to shorten my code for better understanding, but it seems that I should edit and share the whole code. I did so and added the whole code.

Comment: Yeah, because in your entire code you not yet define userA and userB

Comment: @free i think you set -1 or 1 instead of call `sortFn`